# Javascript reload page real-time results

Tags: javascript, real-time

I know i can use javascript to refresh the page after a certain amount of time;

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to reload the page once a new field has been added/updated in the database to display data in real-time instead of "F5"

Comment: You mean you can't find out to refresh a page with javascript *anywhere* on Google?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: And look to the right -------------->

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to refresh a page using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294842/how-to-refresh-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page auto reload with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296685/page-auto-reload-with-parameters)

Comment: Please do not update your question with horrible code we all hate

Comment: The answer is yes. In the callback from an Ajax call!

Comment: As you can probably tell by the question, im not familiar with javascript or ajax, so posting this question was to ask for help, not be criticized for asking a "dumb question".

Comment: I did not tell you that. However at SO a minimum of research is expected and it is not possible to not have found anything on the net by simply googling for "update html after database insert"

Comment: i havent used any html in my script, its PHP as you'll see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658441/issues-with-datetime-in-database

Comment: To the browser its html.  @mplungjan mentioned that search because performing a page refresh is insanely costly when all you need to do pass in some small data and update the dom.

Comment: Are you inserting the data into the database or could someone else be?

Comment: If you are, then you could dynamically update the page view without refreshing the page.  If you aren't, then you either could use a database trigger event to trigger the insert event, or you could use a polling mechanism (setTimeout/setInterval) on the front-end to read from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup insert and update triggers to send an event that would cause a callback to execute in the application. The application can then invoke a registered JS callback function. You can see a description here https://stackoverflow.com/a/812803/1418005

Answer (score 0):

### Invoke Notifications via MySQL Triggers on UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE

This works in most Databases and can be used to send server-sent events directly to the browser when something changes *(such as when a field is updated and you need to notify the customer instantly)*.

Use `Database Triggers` and `Server-Sent Event Notifications` which sends event triggers **directly to the browser** with the following - [Invoke pusher when mysql has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474012/invoke-pusher-when-mysql-has-changed?answertab=active#tab-top) for anything that changes on the database.  This happens in Real-time for real-time results.

Answer (score -1):

You should not refresh the page after a certain amount of time, it is rather bothersome to the user.  You should use a setInterval to send another request to the server to dynamically update the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
setInterval(fn, 5000);

function fn() {
  alert('???');
}
```

EDIT in Response:
You could either use a database trigger event to trigger the insert event and then notify the client to read, or you could use a polling mechanism - query db every 60 seconds using (setTimeout/setInterval).  This could be done using jQuery ajax or any other XHR mechanism.

For ex:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'server.php/GetPageData' // or GetPageUpdate
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Better [mdn setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Comment: Yes, this sounds more suited. Is it possible to refresh the page after a field has been inserted/updated?