# Convert second to day hour min second format

Tags: php, datetime, format

I got working times type is second.How can I convert 6010 second to  0 day ,0 hour ,10 min ,10 second in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want an integer division technique.

```
days = seconds / ( 24 * 60 * 60 )
seconds -= ( days * ( 24 * 60 * 60 ) )

hours = seconds / ( 60 * 60 )
seconds -= ( hours * ( 60 * 60 ) )

minutes = seconds / 60
seconds -= ( minutes * 60 )
```

Implementing this in PHP should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$mins = floor(($seconds - ($hours*3600)) / 60);
```

Comment: why not include link where you got it from? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856293/how-to-convert-seconds-to-time-format