# how to sum times in where dates are same in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to build a time-tracker, in where it has a 'time_tracks' table. An employee can track the time many times in a single day. Now I want to sum the 'total_time' where 'track_date' are same. Would someone help me to find out the expected results, please! Here is my 'trackForToday' function is bellow-

```
public function trackForToday()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $last_date = TimeTrack::where('employee_id', $user_id)->select('track_date')->orderBy('track_date', 'DESC')->first();
    $last_work_time = TimeTrack::where('employee_id', $user_id)->where('track_date', $last_date->track_date)->get();

    return view('employee.time-tracker.today');
}
```

And this is my 'time_tracks' table- 
[image]

Comment: you should consider total_time in seconds, then you could easily use `sum()` to get the total

Comment: What is the type of the `total_time` column?

Comment: I would store date and time as a single entity. If Ann employee works past midnight then you can come to a decision about how to allocate those hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sum()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sum) collection method and as you are using `time type` as column type(seems) , you may need to `convert` it to seconds before summing it.

```
$total_time = TimeTrack::where('employee_id', $user_id)->where('track_date', $last_date->track_date)->sum(DB::raw("TIME_TO_SEC(total_time)"));
```

To get data of a specific track date-

```
$track_date = '2018-03-01';
$total_time = TimeTrack::where('track_date', $track_date)->sum(DB::raw("TIME_TO_SEC(total_time)"));
```

Last to `show` it, you need to `convert` back to `time format`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856293/how-to-convert-seconds-to-time-format) link for that.

> The `sum` method returns the sum of all items in the collection. If the collection contains `nested` arrays or objects, you should `pass a key` to use for determining which values to sum.

Comment: For  '2018-03-01' what should I write in the query?

Comment: is this track date??

Comment: yes, this is track date. You answered only for last_date , I want also to sum the total_time for any date.

Comment: My 'track_date' may different date. 'track_date' is inputted by an employee from the front end, so, I can not fix the date.

Comment: just change the track date to your input date like `$request->input('track_date')`

Comment: Ok. Now I want to show these total time to date wise to the employee.What should I write then?

Comment: for a specific date, you can do like my answer, for all dates make a froup by query