# Convert current time(dt) from seconds to real time format(hour and minute)

Tags: java, android, api, datetime, retrofit

I was able to display some weather data on my app using retrofit from a JSON response, but the current time(dt), sunrise, and sunset displays on my textviews as seconds i.e 1612730263.
So I need to convert the time to a real-time format(hour and minute) e.g 9:30 PM. **Disclaimer**:
[Java: Date from unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp) and [How to convert seconds to time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856293/how-to-convert-seconds-to-time-format) doesn't work for me because my response is from an API. Therefore my question is not a duplicate.

My API response:

```
    {
   "lat":9.0765,
   "lon":7.3986,
   "timezone":"Africa/Lagos",
   "timezone_offset":3600,
   "current":{
      "dt":1612779720,
      "sunrise":1612763455,
      "sunset":1612805901,
      "temp":304.15,
      "feels_like":302.14,
      "pressure":1013,
      "humidity":33,
      "dew_point":286,
      "uvi":8.42,
      "clouds":42,
      "visibility":7000,
      "wind_speed":4.12,
      "wind_deg":100,
      "weather":[
         {
            "id":802,
            "main":"Clouds",
            "description":"scattered clouds",
            "icon":"03d"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My Retrofit call for the time in **HomeActivity**:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        WeatherService service = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);
        Call<WeatherResponse> call = service.getCurrentWeatherData(lat, lon, AppId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NonNull Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    WeatherResponse weatherResponse = response.body();
                    assert weatherResponse != null;

                    assert response.body() != null;
// current time textview
                  time_field.setText(String.valueOf(response.body().getCurrent().getDt()));
```

My Retrofit call for the time & in **FirstFragment**:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
                WeatherService service = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);
                Call<WeatherResponse> call = service.getCurrentWeatherData(lat, lon, AppId);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NonNull Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
                        if (response.code() == 200) {
                            WeatherResponse weatherResponse = response.body();
                            assert weatherResponse != null;

                            assert response.body() != null; 
// sunrise & sunset time textviews                                                             
rise_time.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getSunrise() + " AM");                                
set_time.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getSunset() + " PM");
```

**EDIT**

**WeatherResponse.java**:

```
public class WeatherResponse {

    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private Double lat;
    @SerializedName("lon")
    @Expose
    private Double lon;
    @SerializedName("timezone")
    @Expose
    private String timezone;
    @SerializedName("timezone_offset")
    @Expose
    private Integer timezoneOffset;
    @SerializedName("current")
    @Expose
    private Current current;

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getTimezone() {
        return timezone;
    }

    public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    public Integer getTimezoneOffset() {
        return timezoneOffset;
    }

    public void setTimezoneOffset(Integer timezoneOffset) {
        this.timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset;
    }

    public Current getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(Current current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

}
```

**Current.java**:

```
public class Current {

    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private Integer dt;
    @SerializedName("sunrise")
    @Expose
    private Integer sunrise;
    @SerializedName("sunset")
    @Expose
    private Integer sunset;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private Double temp;
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    @Expose
    private Double feelsLike;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    @Expose
    private Integer pressure;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private Integer humidity;
    @SerializedName("dew_point")
    @Expose
    private Double dewPoint;
    @SerializedName("uvi")
    @Expose
    private Double uvi;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    @Expose
    private Integer clouds;
    @SerializedName("visibility")
    @Expose
    private Integer visibility;
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    @Expose
    private Double windSpeed;
    @SerializedName("wind_deg")
    @Expose
    private Integer windDeg;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<Weather> weather = null;

    public Integer getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(Integer dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public Integer getSunrise() {
        return sunrise;
    }

    public void setSunrise(Integer sunrise) {
        this.sunrise = sunrise;
    }

    public Integer getSunset() {
        return sunset;
    }

    public void setSunset(Integer sunset) {
        this.sunset = sunset;
    }

    public Double getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(Double temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public Double getFeelsLike() {
        return feelsLike;
    }

    public void setFeelsLike(Double feelsLike) {
        this.feelsLike = feelsLike;
    }

    public Integer getPressure() {
        return pressure;
    }

    public void setPressure(Integer pressure) {
        this.pressure = pressure;
    }

    public Integer getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public void setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }

    public Double getDewPoint() {
        return dewPoint;
    }

    public void setDewPoint(Double dewPoint) {
        this.dewPoint = dewPoint;
    }

    public Double getUvi() {
        return uvi;
    }

    public void setUvi(Double uvi) {
        this.uvi = uvi;
    }

    public Integer getClouds() {
        return clouds;
    }

    public void setClouds(Integer clouds) {
        this.clouds = clouds;
    }

    public Integer getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(Integer visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    public Double getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    public void setWindSpeed(Double windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    public Integer getWindDeg() {
        return windDeg;
    }

    public void setWindDeg(Integer windDeg) {
        this.windDeg = windDeg;
    }

    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }
}
```

Please I need the code provided to be linked to my app so that it will be easier to implement it. I have basic knowledge of dt conversion, but not from a weather API response. I think using my textviews to convert the data will be better(If there's any way you can use my textviews to do it)

Comment: You will need to read the documentation for the Web service that you are calling to determine how to interpret the values being returned in the JSON. The time values look like seconds since the Unix epoch.

Comment: I've read the full documentation https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api, there's no indication on how to interpret the values

Comment: The page that you linked to has a "Fields in API response" section that describes how to interpret the values in the response.

Comment: That was exactly the field I called in my retrofit. Well I think you're making a point, the data was displayed in seconds, so I need to convert it to hour and minute real-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Date from unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert seconds to time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856293/how-to-convert-seconds-to-time-format)

Comment: None answers my question because i'm getting the response from an API, using their method doesn't work for me

Comment: Please, can you indicate in your question how does the `WeatherResponse` class look like?

Comment: @jccampanero okay, I've done that

Comment: Thank you very much @Chinez. Please, can you include the source code of the Current class as well? These classes, were machine generated in any way? Did you program them manually?

Comment: @Jccampanero Okay, I've done that. I'm sorry for taking too long, have been having tight lectures. Yes the classes were machine-generated using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to obtain the right date patterns right from the information returned in the `WeatherResponse` and related classes.

For this purpose, you need to customize the Gson library you are using in your code to deserialize the information returned by the openweathermap API by Retrofit.

There are several ways to do this but, as far as you have the ability to modify the classes generated by `jsonschema2pojo`, I would suggest the following approach.

The idea consists basically in implement a [custom Gson deserializer](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#writing-a-deserializer) to handle the required transformation.

You can opt for implement this custom deserializer for the whole `Current` class but I think it will be easier to only handle the deserialization of the necessary fields.

For that purpose, first, let's create a new type; it will serve as a marker for the fields that require the custom deserialization. For example:

```java
public class PrettyTime {

  private String value;

  public PrettyTime() {
  }

  public PrettyTime(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getValue();
  }
}
```

Apply this marker to the fields you need the conversion in the `Current` class:

```java
public class Current {

  @SerializedName("dt")
  @Expose
  private PrettyTime dt;
  @SerializedName("sunrise")
  @Expose
  private PrettyTime sunrise;
  @SerializedName("sunset")
  @Expose
  private PrettyTime sunset;

  // The rest of the fields and setters and getters

  public PrettyTime getDt() {
    return dt;
  }

  public void setDt(PrettyTime dt) {
    this.dt = dt;
  }

  public PrettyTime getSunrise() {
    return sunrise;
  }

  public void setSunrise(PrettyTime sunrise) {
    this.sunrise = sunrise;
  }

  public PrettyTime getSunset() {
    return sunset;
  }

  public void setSunset(PrettyTime sunset) {
    this.sunset = sunset;
  }
  
}
```

Next, let's create the custom deserializer:

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class PrettyTimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<PrettyTime> {
  // Modify the date pattern as you consider appropriate
  private static final SimpleDateFormat HMM = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

  public PrettyTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {
    final long seconds = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong();
    final Date date = new Date(seconds * 1000);
    final String prettyFormatted = HMM.format(date);
    return new PrettyTime(prettyFormatted);
  }
}
```

Finally, integrate this deserializer in your code, both in the `HomeActivity` and `FirstFragment` classes:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .registerTypeAdapter(PrettyTime.class, new PrettyTimeDeserializer())
  .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
  // Please note the gson argument
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
  .build()
;

// The rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The deserialization worked and the app finally displays real-time! Though the problem now is that the sunrise and sunset displays double AM & PM, i.e 9:30 PM PM. I want to eliminate one, please help

Comment: Also if you have an idea of getting the actual temp i.e from temp":304.15 to 30. I would appreciate, but if you can't, I'll just post it as a new question, thanks

Comment: Hi @Chinez. I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful. Of course, please, see the edited answer: to remove the AM/PM part from the date string you need to change the pattern `hh:mm a` to `hh:mm`. Having said that, please, consider use the `hh:mm a` pattern instead of manually add the AM/PM afterwards in your code. Regarding the `temp` field issue, you can follow a similar approach to the one provided for these dates but, according to the [API documentation](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api#data), I think a better approach will be to provide the `units` parameter.

Comment: With the appropriate value, something like: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&units=metric. Pay attention to the units `metric` value. It will return the information directly in Celsius degrees. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```java
String timezone = "Africa/Lagos"; // "timezone":"Africa/Lagos"
long dt = 1612779720L; // "dt":1612779720
long sunriseTime = 1612763455L; // "sunrise":1612763455
long sunsetTime = 1612805901L; // "sunset":1612805901
double temp = 304.15D; // "temp":304.15 (in Kelvin).
        
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm aa"); // h:mm AM/PM (hh:mm aa == hh:mm AM/PM).
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
        
// current local time
String time = sdf.format(new Date(dt));
// sunrise
String sunrise = sdf.format(new Date(sunriseTime));
// sunset
String sunset = sdf.format(new Date(sunsetTime));
// temperature in Celcius
String celcius = String.format("%.2f °C", temp - 273.16D);
// temperature in Fahrenheit
String fahrenheit = String.format("%.2f °F", ((temp - 273D) * 9D/5D) + 32D);
        
System.out.println(time); //4:59 PM
System.out.println(sunrise); //4:59 PM
System.out.println(sunset); //5:00 PM
System.out.println(celcius); //30.99 °C
System.out.println(fahrenheit); //88.07 °F
```

Comment: Using this code. While it didn't give any error, it didn't work. I think using my textviews to convert the data will be better(If there's anyway you can use my textviews to do it)

Comment: `response.body().getCurrent()`. What type of class is this returns? Is it `WeatherResponse`? e.g. `WeatherResponse curr = response.body().getCurrent()`?

Comment: Using the API https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api, the current class returns some current weather data. I've included the source code up for more information

Comment: I'm very sorry for replying late, been very busy with lectures lately

Answer (score 0):

Just create a date object with that value as parameter:

```java
java.util.Date time=new java.util.Date(((long)timeStamp)*1000);
```

As java is expecting milliseconds as a parameter, you need to multiply your value (in seconds) by 1000.

Comment: Wrote this on my code, it  says' time is never used'  and the code doesn't work

Comment: @Chinez You should know some basics like how to use variables and objects before working with APIs... The code I've posted creates a Date object from any timestamp you give it. Here, your timestamp is the result of `dt`, which you can isolate using basic String operations. I won't deliver ready-to-bake-code, but some more keywords to research about: `String.split`, `java Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `java parse Integer`.

Comment: Well, I learnt the basics before working. you don't need to deliver ready-to-bake-code, just answer if you know how, thanks

Comment: @Chinez Try looking into the keywords I've sent and see if they can help you to nail down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Instant#ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) to get the `Instant` which you can convert into `ZonedDateTime` for the specified timezone ID and then format the obtained `ZonedDateTime` using `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(
                "Sunrise date and time with timezone: " + getDateTimeWithTzString(1608529251L, "Africa/Lagos"));
        System.out.println("Sunrise date and time: " + getDateTimeString(1608529251L, "Africa/Lagos"));
        System.out.println("Sunrise time: " + getTimeString(1608529251L, "Africa/Lagos"));
        System.out.println("Date: " + getDateString(1608529251L, "Africa/Lagos"));
    }

    static String getDateTimeWithTzString(long epochSecond, String strTz) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(strTz);
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(zoneId);
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd h:m:s a '['VV']'", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return zdt.format(dtf);
    }

    static String getDateTimeString(long epochSecond, String strTz) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(strTz);
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(zoneId);
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd h:m:s a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return zdt.format(dtf);
    }

    static String getTimeString(long epochSecond, String strTz) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(strTz);
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(zoneId);
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m:s a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return zdt.format(dtf);
    }

    static String getDateString(long epochSecond, String strTz) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(strTz);
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(zoneId);
        return zdt.toLocalDate().toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sunrise date and time with timezone: 2020-12-21 6:40:51 AM [Africa/Lagos]
Sunrise date and time: 2020-12-21 6:40:51 AM
Sunrise time: 6:40:51 AM
Date: 2020-12-21
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: I appreciate your effort towards helping me, but this didn't work because this is like getting an independent time(separate from the app), it links no connection from the app, so running it couldn't display it in hour/minute format